# What is causing the 'WrongThreadException' in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

I want to integrate a C++ project in Unity. Unity provides a mechanism called [I2CPP](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html) (Intermediate Language To C++) which allows to add C++ code to your unity project. I've created a simple C++ class and header in a "Blank App (Universal Windows C++/CX)" project in Visual Studio.

```
// header
namespace SomeNamespace {
    public ref class MyRuntimeClass sealed
    {
        public:
            // Constructor
            MyRuntimeClass();

            // Method to check if initialized
            bool IsClassInitialized();

        private:
            bool _isRuntimeInitialized = false;
    };
}
```

and

```
// implementation
using SomeNamespace;
MyRuntimeClass::MyRuntimeClass()
{
    _isRuntimeInitialized = true;
}

bool MyRuntimeClass::IsClassInitialized()
{
    return _isRuntimeInitialized;
};
```

I've made in Unity a simple project and made the necessary changes in the Player settings outlined in the documentation. I also added a cube as a game object and attached to the cube a script which uses my C++ code, i.e.

```
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
using SomeNamespace;
#endif

public class RuntimeSampleUnity : MonoBehaviour
{
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
    private MyRuntimeClass _myRuntimeClass;
#endif

    // Default MonoBehaviour method
    void Start()
    {
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
        // New instance of runtime class
        _myRuntimeClass = new MyRuntimeClass();

        // Check to see if we initialized C++ runtime component
        var isInit = _myRuntimeClass.IsClassInitialized();
        Debug.LogFormat("MyRuntimeClass: {0}", isInit);
#endif
    }
}
```

In a final step, I've added the winmd file from the C++ project to my assets in Unity. The project builds fine, but when I run the project I get an `Platform.WrongThreadException: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread`. What is causing this exception (and how do I fix it)?

EDIT: To elaborate a bit why I'm doing what I'm doing: Microsoft provides a [project](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLensForCV) which shows how to integrate OpenCV (C++) to HoloLens-based projects. While it provides a UWP project which mixes OpenCV and C#, it doesn't show how to integrate this particular project into Unity. [Somebody actually made this possible via I2CPP](https://doughtmw.github.io/posts/HoloLensForCV-Unity-1). While I ran into issues using his Visual Studio 2017 based project into Visual Studio 2019, I've tried to make a minimal example to understand how it (basically) works.

Comment: Ive not heard of it being used to add c++ to a project

Comment: I think IL2CPP is just the compiler convertin gyour code into c++ code. I may be mistaking but I don't think it is related to C++ plugin integration. On a side note, whoever downvoted, you'd be kind enough to explain why. The question is detailed and relevant.

Comment: Are you trying to run a built exe or are you just clicking the play button in the editor?

Comment: I've tried to built an executable. I've did this via the "build and run" command.

Comment: Did you post the the whole code? What's the callstack for that exception? That exception usually is thrown when your C++ code is calling stuff from the wrong thread. It's unlikely this has anything to do with IL2CPP.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're misunderstanding the concept of IL2CPP.

> IL2CPP (Intermediate Language To C++) is a Unity-developed scripting
>   backend  which you can use as an alternative to Mono when building
>   projects for various platforms. When building a project using IL2CPP,
>   **Unity converts IL code from scripts  and assemblies to C++**, before
>   creating a native binary file (.exe, apk, .xap, for example) for your
>   chosen platform. Some of the uses for IL2CPP include increasing the
>   performance, security, and platform compatibility of your Unity
>   projects.

To use C++ you have to write a [Native Plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html).

Comment: To my understand of the documentation you can actually use IL2CPP for adding external C++ code. From the documentation "Use Windows Runtime support to call into both native system Windows Runtime APIs as well as custom .winmd files directly from managed code (scripts and DLLs)". See also the background on using  OpenCV+Unity in a HoloLens project above.